# Meaning of a statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to understand the meaning of the following line in the code mentioned below: (As in how to read that line?)

```
print('#%*s' % (a, '#') if a else '')
```

From this code:

```
lines = int(input("Enter number of lines for pattern: "))
for a in range(lines):
    print('#%*s' % (a, '#') if a else '')
```

Comment: The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) i excellent. Have you tried reading it? And there's quite a lot happening in the line you're wondering about, can you be more precise about what you have doubts about?

Comment: I'd say that in this case pointing to the documentation wouldn't be enough. If you don't know about the "old-style" string formatting in Python, understanding the code in the question won't be so easy.

Answer (score 2):

This is a conditional expression:

```
'#%*s' % (a, '#') if a else ''
```

Read it like this: `if` the variable `a` is not null and not empty format it, `else` the expression evaluates to the empty string `''`. Now for the format part (which uses the [old % syntax](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#1-old-style-string-formatting-operator)):

```
'#%*s' % (a, '#')
```

It says: print an `#`, then `a` number of spaces and finally one last `#` character. The `*` gets substituted with the value of `a` and then the format string is applied to the `#` character For example, if `a = 5` the above expression will evaluate to this:

```
'#%5s' % '#'
```

Which we can print and see the result:

```
print('#%5s' % '#')
#    #
```

Notice that the `%` syntax is deprecated, in modern Python the recommendation is to use [`str.format`](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#2-new-style-string-formatting-strformat) or even better, [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#3-string-interpolation-f-strings-python-36) for Python 3.6+.

Answer (score 0):

You can see some [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/) examples here. So your formatting does something like:

> Format the output (your `#`) as a string and place an additional `#`
>   at the end of the line. Fill the line with so many spaces that the
>   line has a total length of `a`. If `a` is zero and so the `if`
>   statement is `FALSE` print and empty line.

```
Enter number of lines for pattern: 9

##
# #
#  #
#   #
#    #
#     #
#      #
#       #
```

A modern solution for the same output would be looking like this:

```
lines = int(input("Enter number of lines for pattern: "))
for a in range(lines):
   print(("{:" + str(a) + "}{}").format("#", "#") if a else "")
```